# How to change keyboard layout change shortcut in Xubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu

In normal Ubuntu it is seamlessly done through System → Preferences → Keyboard → Options dialog. Xubuntu's Xfce desktop lacks this dialog. Surprisingly my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file is empty. I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This is a method that works on any X11 system, not just Xubuntu. In the terminal emulator run something like this:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -variant ',winkeys' -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll'
```

And your layouts will switch immediately. This example will make a keyboard two-layout (US international and Russian Windows-like), switched by Alt-Shift, ScrollLock light will indicate the active layout.

But this is a temporary setting, it will not be preserved for the future sessions. I don't know what configuration mechanism is suggested in Xubuntu.

Comment: This is the best solution ever - worked like a charm on my Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you are looking for [here](http://swiss.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=850899)

Hope this will help you!